# SQL Server COALESCE function with WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

I want to concatenate my SQL Server table's column value in `Varchar` parameter. For that I am using the `COALESCE` function. But when I use it with `Select` statement with `Where` clause, I think it's not taking where clause conditions.

```
SELECT 
    @UserIds = COALESCE(@UserIds,'') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), UserID) +','      
FROM vw_Users               
WHERE GroupID = @GroupID                                        
  AND ISNULL(Active_yn, 'Y') = 'Y'            
  AND ISNULL(Delete_YN, 'N') = 'N'
```

So can anybody help me out on this?

Comment: What does this code do? What did you **expect** it to do??

Comment: it should select all the userid's from related table into comma separated string.

Comment: And what **does it do**??

Comment: what is the actual output you are getting with this query?

Comment: the `coalesce` function shouldn't affect the `where` clause at all. I think that the `select` clause is actually "executed" after the `where` clause

Comment: Post some sample data and the rows that you expect in output..

Comment: Instead of coalesce use FOR XML PATH with stuff will resolve your issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If corecctly understood your problem, you can use `CASE` something like:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(Active_yn, 'Y') = 'Y' 
              AND ISNULL(Delete_YN, 'N') = 'N' 
              AND GroupID = @GroupID THEN @UserIds = COALESCE(@UserIds,'') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), UserID) +','  
         ELSE Condition 
    END    
FROM vw_Users
```

In this case It will concatenate only when all conditions meet, otherwise you can pass condition to `ELSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine, where conditions are correct, just a small change in COALESCE function to concatenate "," only when needed. Here's a sample with data:

```
DECLARE @UserIds VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @GroupID INT = 1;

WITH vw_Users (UserID, GroupID, Active_YN, Delete_YN) AS (
    SELECT 1, 1, 'Y', 'N' UNION ALL -- valid value
    SELECT 2, 1, 'Y', 'N' UNION ALL -- valid value

    SELECT 3, 1, 'N', 'N' UNION ALL -- invalid value because Active_YN <> 'Y'
    SELECT 4, 1, 'Y', 'Y' UNION ALL -- invalid value because Deleted_YN <> 'N'
    SELECT 5, 2, 'Y', 'N'           -- invalid value because GroupID <> 1
)
SELECT 
    @UserIds = COALESCE(@UserIds + ',','') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), UserID)
FROM vw_Users               
WHERE GroupID = @GroupID                                        
  AND ISNULL(Active_yn, 'Y') = 'Y'            
  AND ISNULL(Delete_YN, 'N') = 'N' 

SELECT @UserIds --> 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try following,

```
Declare @cols nvarchar(max) = ''
SELECT  @cols = 
STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
        ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t2.UserID)
        FROM  vw_Users AS t2
        WHERE GroupID = @GroupID                                        
        AND ISNULL(Active_yn, 'Y') = 'Y'            
        AND ISNULL(Delete_YN, 'N') = 'N' 
        FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')

select @cols
```

Here is [Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64f51/9)

Comment: i tried with this but the output did not contains the where conditions.

Comment: give me fiddle if you have or give me sample data the I can help you better.